# WordPress - How to sanitize multi-line text from a textarea without losing line breaks?

Tags: php, wordpress, textarea, line-breaks, sanitize

If I sanitize and save some meta text (called 'message') entered by the user like like this...

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'message', sanitize_text_field($_POST['message']));
```

...and then retrieve and attempt to re-display the text like this...

```
echo '<textarea id="message" name="message">' . esc_textarea( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'message', true ) ) . '</textarea>';
```

...all the line breaks get lost.

In accordance with the WordPress codex, the line breaks are being stripped out by the sanitize_text_field() function. So how can I sanitize the text entered by the user without losing their line breaks?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A more elegant solution:

```
update_post_meta(
    $post_id,
    'message',
    implode( "\n", array_map( 'sanitize_textarea_field', explode( "\n", $_POST['message'] ) ) )
);
```

Use `sanitize_text_field` if you want to sanitize text field.

Comment: Thank you - this is not only elegant, but brilliant.

Comment: I would not change the user input but rather just insert a post meta with using $wpdb->query() directly, which would avoid a WordPress's boredom of meta input sanitization, which you don't need for your particular case.

Answer (score 53):

Since Wordpress 4.7.0

Use [sanitize_textarea_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_textarea_field/) instead of sanitize_text_field

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a shame there's no way to change the top answer - esp. as it could take years for this answer to get more upvotes that the selected top answer.

Comment: This is the one you all are looking for. Should replace the other answers.

Comment: This is the true solution.

Answer (score 1):

If line breaks are the *only* thing `sanitize_text_field` is removing that you want to keep, you could just `str_replace` for `"\n"` before and after calling `sanitize_text_field`.

```
$fake_newline = '--OMGKEEPTHISNEWLINE--'; # or some unique string
$escaped_newlines = str_replace("\n", $fake_newline, $_POST['message']);
$sanitized = sanitize_text_field($escaped_newlines);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'message', str_replace($fake_newline", "\n", $sanitized));
```

If you want to customize sanitization more, you should probably rely on more fine-grained `sanitize_*` functions provided by WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for this. A couple of errors in your code, but I get the idea. Here's the working code:

$NEW_LINE = "\n";
$NEW_LINE_SUBSTITUTE = "NEWLINE-SUBSTITUTE";
update_post_meta($post_id, 'message', sanitize_text_field( str_replace($NEW_LINE, $NEW_LINE_SUBSTITUTE, $_POST['message'] )) );
echo '<textarea id="message" name="message">' . str_replace($NEW_LINE_SUBSTITUTE, $NEW_LINE,  esc_textarea( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'message', true ) ) ) . '</textarea>';

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to use this method myself, and find that apostrophes in the textarea are escaped by backslashes on the way in, which then aren't removed by esc_textarea on the way out.

So I've ended up having to use

```
stripslashes( esc_textarea( $THING ) )
```

to successfully remove them from the textarea when redisplaying.

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything, the only way I was able to make this work was like this:

function.php

```
wp_customize->add_section('section_id', array(
    'title' => __('custom_section', 'theme_name'),
    'priority' => 10,
    'description' => 'Custom section description',
));

$wp_customize->add_setting('custom_field', array(
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_textarea_field',
));

$wp_customize->add_control('custom_field', array(
    'type' => 'textarea',
    'section' => 'custom_section',
    'label' => __('Custom text area with multiline brakes'),
));
```

Display in front (ex. footer.php)

```
<?php $custom_field= get_theme_mod('custom_field');
    if ($custom_field) {
        echo nl2br( esc_html( $custom_field) );
} ?>
```

Must use `'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_textarea_field'` and `nl2br( esc_html())` to work.